# Issues using YAML to set up an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have to set up an S3 bucket from YAML that should be named sayit and allows web files to be publicly accessible. Here's what I came up with.

```
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: sayit
      WebsiteConfiguration:
        IndexDocument: voice-label.html
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
```

When I put it into CloudFormation it created an S3 bucket named cf-templates-yjnwxmkt6wo6, and when I configured it for static web hosting and went to the endpoint it just gave me a 403 error. Access denied. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your template (with a different bucket name) and it correctly created the bucket.

If you want the *contents* of the bucket to be accessible to the Internet, you will need to add a [Bucket Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html) to the template. (Use the sample template, adjusting it for `S3Bucket`.)

The *cf-templates* bucket is simply used by CloudFormation to store your template. Any template you launch in that region will use the same bucket. You can delete it if you wish, or just keep it around.

Comment: I did a bit of research, is there a way to create a bucket policy in the same file I create the bucket from? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: Yes, copy [the sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html#w2ab2c21c10d999c13) and modify the `Ref` to point to your bucket resource in the same template.